# What does pilcrow (¶) in a SQL Server (Latin1 charset) database mean?

Tags: sql-server, internet-explorer-8, tinymce, paste

I have a webapp where contents are getting pasted via *TinyMCE*. I can see some pilcrow (¶) symbols when I see the contents in my DB client called *Dbeaver*. Copying this from clipboard using the DB Client to *VIM* displays it as next line.

1. What character that shows up as ¶ as a standard?
2. Do they just show up as ¶ and is it different from the real unicode (186) pilcrow?
3. Are these real carriage returns if so what scenarios can cause it to reach to DB literally ?

Answer (score 1):

It's the line feed character which is directly entering the system!